# How to get to elements of JSON-P data

Tags: javascript, json

I have a data feed from Google api below:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AhySzEddwIC1dEtpWF9hQUhCWURZNEViUmpUeVgwdGc/1/public/basic?alt=json

I have been working with it for a while but cant manage to get to the specific names of the FTSE 100 companies.

currently i am using the below code to get the data but I don't get what i expected as an output in console.

```
$(function() {
    data = $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AhySzEddwIC1dEtpWF9hQUhCWURZNEViUmpUeVgwdGc/1/public/basic?alt=json-in-script"), 


  console.log(data);

});
```

What I do get in console is this stuff?

```
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
     abort: function (e){var t=e||w;return u&&u.abort(t),k(0,t),this}
     always: function (){return i.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}
     etc etc
```

I was looking to log all the names of the FTSE 100 companies, any help?

Thanks,
Ewan

Comment: What you are getting from `getJSON` is a promise, not the actual returned value because the data will be returned some time in the future (asynchronously). You need to pass in a callback to handle the returned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write:

```
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com....", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

### Why?

As stated in [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) docs:

> As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of
>   the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR,"
>   returned by `$.getJSON()` implements the Promise interface, giving it
>   all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred
>   object for more information).

The `getJson` method returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object, that is what you are printing in the console. In simple terms, a promise is something that will be available in the future, but not now. The function passed as paremeter (the callback function) will be called once the ajax call actually returns the data.